# Electron.js Connection Problem with openvidu

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an project with vue electron builder and node.js.
While i sending request from Openvidu server, i have an error.
This error is;

```
webSocketWithReconnection.js?714c:61 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:4443/openvidu' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

How can i fix.?

Answer (score 1):

You must configure your Electron app to accept self-signed SSL certificates if you are going to use a local development OpenVidu deployment.
In your Electron app add: https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-tutorials/blob/f39d38fe14ea48dcb17c4fff4c39cc198f36ab8a/openvidu-electron/src/main.js#L69-L74

Comment: Thank you very match. It's work.!! ((: